# TORQUE : How to prohibit using of jobs array submission for all users : qsub -t?

Tags: cluster-computing, pbs, qsub, torque

On my torque server manager I would like to prohibit using of jobs array submission for all users: `qsub -t`.

In the official doc I have found pbs parameters who can manage this: `max_job_array_size`and `max_slot_limit`.

I would like to know if I set those parameters to 0 : `qmgr -c 'set server max_job_array_size=0'` and `qmgr -c 'set server max_slot_limit=0'` It will effectively prevent submitting array jobs ?

any other suggestion are welcomed :) maybe a rule in the `sudoers file` ?
regards

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you set max_array_size to 0, all array submissions will be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply reject any `qsub -t` submissions with the job submit filter. That will also give you the opportunity to give educational feedback. Your other idea about `max_job_array_size` seems reasonable, too, but you'll have to test it to find out if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you all :) I will test both solution.

Answer (score 1):

qmgr -c 'set server max_job_array_size=0' and qmgr -c 'set server max_slot_limit=0' is working well.